# Assign php variable to href along with #

Tags: php, html

How to assign `$trow[tbl_NO]` included `#`

```
while($trow = mysql_fetch_array($tresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   

     echo"<tr><td class='w3-blue'><a href='"#".$trow['tbl_no']' style='font-size:20px;color:white'>".$trow["tbl_no"]."</a></td></tr>";  
}
```

Comment: Use quotation marks properly. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for more information

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
echo"<tr><td class='w3-blue'><a href='#".$trow['tbl_no']."' style='font-size:20px;color:white'>".$trow["tbl_no"]."</a></td></tr>";
```

Comment: echo " ..... {$trow['tbl_no']} ..."; also can work if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @OfirBaruch he is asking to include `#` in href. because of the double quote before it the rest was considered as comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat variable like this

```
while($trow = mysql_fetch_array($tresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {   

      echo"<tr><td class='w3-blue'><a href='#".$trow['tbl_no']."' style='font-size:20px;color:white'>".$trow["tbl_no"]."</a></td></tr>";  

     }
```